# Get transaction id from new relic during tests

Tags: trace, newrelic

I am using Newrelic to get insights on my golang app. I am trying to test a middleware that will log whenever a request comes with a proper new relic header. ( "Newrelic":"eyXXXXXXX" ).

This is my test :

```
func TestGetNewRelicTraceID(t *testing.T) {

    w := httptest.NewRecorder()

    req := httptest.NewRequest("GET", "/test", nil)
    req.Header.Add("Newrelic", "eyJ2IjpbMCwxXSwiZCI6eyJ0eSI6IkFwcCIsImFwIjoiNDk1Njg4OTcwIiwiYWMiOiIxMzA5OTAiLCJ0eCI6IjE3MGNmYjRiNTBiMTQ2MGIiLCJpZCI6IjQ1NGY0MTFmOWNjYjA1MDgiLCJ0ciI6IjE3MGNmYjRiNTBiMTQ2MGI0MmQ0N2ZkZmQ3MTg2NzM3IiwicHIiOjEuMTI3NTUxLCJzYSI6dHJ1ZSwidGkiOjE2MjEwMTAwMjcwMjIsInRrIjoiMzQ2MDgwIn19")

    app, _ := newrelic.NewApplication(
        newrelic.ConfigAppName("test"),
        newrelic.ConfigLicense("1TI35kweH5xJjYLvDgp6gX1LGbYvJ130n0E5Jecs"),
        newrelic.ConfigDistributedTracerEnabled(true),
        func(cfg *newrelic.Config) {
            cfg.ErrorCollector.RecordPanics = true
        },
    )

    _, fn := newrelic.WrapHandleFunc(app, "/test", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        txn2 := newrelic.FromContext(r.Context())
        nrTraceID := fmt.Sprintf("%s", txn2.GetTraceMetadata().TraceID)
        w.Write([]byte(nrTraceID))
    })
    fn(w, req)
    assert.Equal(t, http.StatusOK, w.Code)

    assert.Equal(t, "170cfb4b50b1460b42d47fdfd7186737", string(w.Body.Bytes()))
}
```

No matter what I do, the test never passes as every run creates a new trace id, instead of using the one coming with the header.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found my problem. So it seems that I have to wait for the connection to the New Relic server to actually take place before running the test. Which means I had to replace **1TI35kweH5xJjYLvDgp6gX1LGbYvJ130n0E5Jecs** with a REAL key. This is very important it seems. Additionally, I had to add this too to the test:

```
err := app.WaitForConnection(time.Second * 10)
require.Nil(t, err)
```

And now it works as expected.